# Loading PHP array from while loop after page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to understand how to load content from a PHP array from a While loop after the page has loaded. The content area that I am trying to display the array in is loaded in a sidebar before the while loop. I was wondering if someone had a way in Javascript or jQuery to do this using a PHP array or if i have to do it all through javascript.

```
<?php
$cityarray = array();
?>

<div id="sidebar">
<?php
    $i=0;
    $cleanArray = array_unique_multidimensional($cityarray);
    foreach($cleanArray as $arr){
        echo "<div><a href='/$arr[1]-$arr[2]/'>$arr[0]</a></div>";
        $i++;
        if($i==6) break;
    }
 ?>
</div>

<div id = "content">
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $title=trim($row['title']);
        $city=trim($row['city']);
        $stateAbv=$row['stateAbv'];
        $mycityUrl = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $city));
        $stateUrl = strtolower($stateAbv);

        //Filling array here that I want to use in the sidebar that aleady loaded.
        $cityarray[] = array($city, $mycityUrl, $stateUrl);

     <div><?php echo title; ?></div>
    }
 </div>

<?php
    function array_unique_multidimensional($input){
        $serialized = array_map('serialize', $input);
        $unique = array_unique($serialized);
        return array_intersect_key($input, $unique);
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: PHP doesn't have any concept of "page loaded". All PHP code will be executed on the server. When PHP is finished executing, the result it produces will then be sent to the client, where all the HTML/JS will be parsed. If you want to run any PHP after the page is loaded, you need to make an Ajax request to another PHP file on page load.

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Another solution would also to be to prepare and create the PHP array (the while loop) _before_ any output in your file and then use it where ever you want in your content.